# Git keep track of clones across multiple computers via SourceTree and Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

So I cloned quite a lot of different git repos all from GitHub which are toolboxes and function packages that I use for my projects. I usually don't modify them but keep them as a clone so I can easily follow updates and changes in these toolboxes and stay up to date.
But I work across multiple computers employing BitBucket and SourceTree as git solution for my own code. Problem now is I clone a repo on one machine but the others/my BitBucket account does not know about this clone and I have to add it on every machine / SourceTree installation manually.
What is the best way to keep track of the cloned projects?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need other GitHub projects which you use as (e.g. as a library) in your project? That's sounds like you could you git submodules: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

You should **fork** the projects on GitHub and push your changes to a branch.